# How do I change my account password?

Tags: support, accounts

I am new to Stack Overflow. I have signed up with the Google account option.

The account is created, but there was no prompt asking for a password. Also, I couldn't find an option to change the password.

Every time I want to log in to my Stack Overflow account, I need to  first enter my Gmail account and then get logged in to my Stack Overflow account. There was no prompt for a password while signing up and there is no email notification with username and password either.

How do I set/reset my account password?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

@Ricky: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The Google and Facebook login options are for the people who don't want to create separate logins for themselves so that there is no need of remembering multiple passwords. Having said that, if you still want to have a different password then you need to sign up with Stack Exchange in order to create your Stack Overflow login. Just follow the steps mentioned below to create your Stack Exchange login:

1. Click on signup and choose Sign up using the Stack Exchange option.
2. Fill in the signup form and click on the Signup button.
3. You will be redirected to an account recovery page. Enter your email address and click on the *Send Recovery Email* button.
4. Log in to your email account and follow the link provided for changing the password.
5. Next time you log in, you got to log in with the Stack Exchange option, and the password can be changed by clicking the "My Logins" link.

Comment: Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers/114704.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Stack Exchange site didn't complained when I registered my account with the same email and new password (I was expecting problems) - It just recognized my account created by Google login and combined them both. Now I can log in via Google or using password.

Comment: It's easier to just go to the Login page, click **"Forgot?"** and put in your email address to get the password reset link. No need to fill out a sign-up form.

Comment: I can confirm that @ADTC 's solution works just fine. No need to jump through more hoops

Comment: So, I have to 'forget my password first? StackOverflow doesn't have the form to change my password?

Comment: This does not add a layer of security since it makes people look for the password, not find it and not change their password. The passwords therefore are not changed for months. This is NOT a good security practice. edit - I'm not referring to the answer but the StackOverflow security policy.

Answer (score 39):

Go to your profile page and you will find a 'My Logins' link

Comment: The My Logins page doesn't let me set a password (or add a Stack Exchange account).

Comment: @MariusGedminas don't you see the Add more logins button?

Comment: For those coming to this off of Google (like me) who are thinking "I want to change my password, not add a new login" - the "My Logins" page is also where you can change your password.

Answer (score 26):

If you have an existing Stack Overflow account that can only log in through Google or Facebook, you can set up a native username/password login by doing this:

1. Click on your reputation/badge numbers near the top right.
2. Click on "Edit Profile," which is just below the search box.
3. Click on "Your logins," on the left under ACCESS.
4. Click on "add more logins..."
5. Enter your email address and the password you want to use.
6. Click "Add login."
7. Once you've verified your email address, you'll be able to log in without a Google or Facebook account.

Comment: Step 2 needs updating to read click on "Settings" tab under the search box.

Comment: Thanks, Dom UIXNZ. I checked just now, though, and my interface shows "Edit profile and settings."

Comment: They probably did incremental rollout of the settings UI changes a few years ago. Step 2 does indeed need to be updated now.

Answer (score 17):

A shortcut way: When you log in to Stack Overflow, in the login form below the password input, there is a link 'Forget?', just click it and enter your email to reset your password, then you will receive an email with instructions to change your password.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using a Google account to sign in to Stack Overflow, you will not be able to change your Stack Overflow account password, because you do NOT HAVE a Stack Overflow password but you will be able to set one using the method described by @Hrishi.

Comment: You will not be able to change it per say but you will be able to set one using the method described by Hrishi.

Comment: @djule5 yes, that's the right answer and alternative

Answer (score 3):

This applies to all login options (GitHub, Google and Facebook). Go to the "list of all 180 Stack Exchange pages" menu in the upper right corner. There click sign out with your Stack Overflow account. Then, in the login field to Stack Overflow account, enter your e-mail address from the login and click "forgot password".

In the message from the e-mail sent to you, you must set a password with the help of the link: "set a password here". You must, because from the same message we learn that: "This email address is associated with an account but no password is associated with it yet, so it can't be used to log in."

As a result, we also get the account in Stack Exchange as described by @Hrishi.

Answer (score 2):

Just log out of your account

[image]

Make sure you log out of all the StackOverflow apps/accounts

Now choose the  Forgot password?  to receive a password reset link.

[image]

The link expires in 30 minutes.

Make sure you generate a very long and very strong password since there is no MFA and you will probably only remember to reset it again in a few months.

This strange way to change one's password is not good security policy as people will look for a password reset option, not find it and skip it for later. Later can become months. This way people are inclined to not change their passwords for long periods of time. This is not good security policy Stack Overflow!