# How can I change my password?

Tags: support

It looks like I can only 'recover' my password on this site. What do I do if I need to reset my password?

There is a similar question [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285427/how-do-i-change-my-account-password) involving use of 'forget-password' but no 'change-password' as such.

Comment: Click the change password button on your logins list: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/2862341

Comment: "recover password"/"forgot password" almost always means "reset password" on any (properly-secured) website.

Comment: Recover is a weird way to call it indeed. But it's simply a term that has stuck around from the wild west days where passwords were stored in plain text and could be emailed to you.

Comment: Go to [the page Nick noted above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/current) and click "Change password" next to one of the listed logins: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6mvv.png (Typo'd in my original comment, woops)

Comment: Have posted as answer. Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to change password?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346663/where-to-change-password)

Answer (score 0):

As of writing (June2022) from the above comments it would be :

Login to Meta > Profile (where reputation is indicated) > Settings > Your Logins (under Access) > Change Password (corresponding to email)